# Manually install Osquery daemon only

Tags: osquery

My task is to install only the OSquery daemon manually I do not want OSquery shell i.e.osqueryi. So I figure out that I need to ship a few files/executables to their respective locations and then start the OSquery service using the command "sudo systemctl start osqueryd".

The files needed to ship are:

- `/usr/lib/systemd/system/osqueryd.service` - service file to start the OSquery service
- `/etc/default/osqueryd` - According to the service file, this location requires one executable.
- `/opt/osquery/bin/osqueryd` - According to the service file, this location requires one executable.
- `/etc/init.d/osqueryd` - Executable daemon
- `/etc/osquery/osquery.conf` - OSquery configuration file

Is this the right way to go about it? Please suggest if there is any other, simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

The osquery shell (`osqueryi`) is actually the same binary as the osquery daemon (`osqueryd`). There is logic in the osquery startup process that [looks at the name of the binary](https://github.com/osquery/osquery/blob/9838f941a2b0dbadac4fa5b9762de7861dc66e46/osquery/core/init.cpp#L268-L275) and starts in either daemon or shell mode. In a typical installation, the `osqueryi` binary is symlinked to the `osqueryd` binary.

Because the `osqueryd` binary is statically linked, "installing" it can be as simple as putting the binary on disk somewhere (eg. `/opt/osquery/bin/osqueryd`). You also probably want a service file that starts that binary (eg. `/usr/lib/systemd/system/osqueryd.service`). It's not strictly required, but you probably also want an osquery configuration file and/or flagfile (so that osquery can actually do something once started).

Note your `/etc/default/osqueryd` should *not* be a binary (it should be [environment variable defaults](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429592/what-is-the-purpose-of-etc-default). `/etc/init.d/osqueryd` is also not required unless you are using the older style init (rather than systemd).